# How to access Google Drive shared link of a folder to get list of all the media items in that link? To be used in an API

Tags: google-api, google-photos-api

If i have a shared link of a google photos album, can I access its contents via an API? Need it to automate word reporting using VBA. Cannot find any document that allows the use of shared link to get contents

Answer (score 0):

You can send a POST request from VBA with the album ID as parameter to return the media items inside.

A sample request could look like this, replace `oauth2-token` with your token and `album-id` with the ID from your shared link:
https://photos.google.com/album/-album-id-

```
POST https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/mediaItems:search
Content-type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer oauth2-token
{
  "pageSize": "100",
  "albumId": "album-id"
}
```

This should return the list of media items in the album:

```
{
  "mediaItems": [
    ... // media ID's here
  ],
  "nextPageToken": "token-for-pagination"
}
```

For more information, you can check the link here: https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/list#listing-album-contents